# Check Internet Connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, connection

I've tried checking if there is a connection to google.com
But this method doesn't work correctly? 
Can you show me my fault? 
Yours Raphael

```
- (BOOL)networkConnected {
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags = 0;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef netReachability;
    BOOL retrievedFlags = NO;
    netReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), [@"http://www.google.com" UTF8String]);

    if (netReachability) {
        retrievedFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(netReachability, &flags);
        CFRelease(netReachability);
    }
    if (!retrievedFlags || !flags) {
        NSLog(@"no");
        return NO;
    }
    NSLog(@"yes");
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should better check [Apple Reacheability example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've got my code from the book Advanced iOS Programming [1]. But the Reachability Samplecode from Apple works much better for me. Thank you for your Tipp. Yours, Raphael        [1] http://www.amazon.de/Advanced-iOS-Programming-Applications-Application/dp/0470971231/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books-intl-de&qid=1299947533&sr=8-1,

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this in objective-c for iPhone?

```
DWORD flags, reserved;
flags = reserved = 0;
if(!InternetGetConnectedState(&flags, reserved))
{
    // No internet connection
} else {
    // Have internet connection
}
```